# How to temporaily block map zoom using Bing Maps API?

Tags: javascript, api, bing-maps

I am using Bing Maps API and I have to temporaily block zoom. Plese tell me how to do that using Java Script? I relize that I have to block some key controls and remove + / - buttons from default Bing Map controls.

Edit;
To hide controlls I can use VEMap.HideDashboard Method.
But how to block response for some keys? Do I have to overload some methods?

Answer (score 0):

You could override the events on map like this:

```
var bloc_zoom = false;
var bloc_pan = false;


function PaintMap()
{
    var VEMap = new VEMap(MapDivId);
    VEMap.AttachEvent("ondoubleclick", block_zoom);
    VEMap.AttachEvent("onkeydown", block_zoom);
    VEMap.AttachEvent("onmousedown", block_pan);
    VEMap.AttachEvent("onmousewheel", block_zoom);
}

function block_zoom(e)
{
     if(block_zoom)
     {
         return true ;
     }
}

function block_pan(e)
{
     if(block_pan)
     {
         return true ;
     }
}
```

Just turn on the flag when you want to block sum and/or Pan